# SQL Stored Procedure Value From Page

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

Can you have a textbox with a word in it and pass this to a SQL stored procedure? I want to use a stored procedure but I am trying to create a search page so I guess I am trying to find out how to keep a stored procedure, but pass the value of the textbox to the stored procedure.

Comment: Some more detail would be nice. Language? WinForm/WebForm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, quite easily, here is a complete [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with examples

Here is the relevant code snippet:

The category name can be set from your control's text property.

```
static void GetSalesByCategory(string connectionString, 
    string categoryName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the command and set its properties.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SalesByCategory";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        // HERE IS What you need.
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = categoryName;

        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        // Open the connection and execute the reader.
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:C}", reader[0], reader[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to mention that there are (what to call them -  tools? libraries? frameworks?) to make this a little easier, e.g. Linq To SQL, Enterprise Library, nHibernate, Entity Framework etc

Comment: Sure, I just assumed to OP was relatively new, as the saying goes he who must fly must first learn to walk etc, i.e. learn what most abstractions do and then abstract away

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  Look into [SQL Parameters](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=SQL+Parameters+in+asp.net&cp=20&qe=U1FMIFBhcmFtZXRlcnMgaW4gYXM&qesig=zdbsS_ThVEB4lUvU2X7Sdg&pkc=AFgZ2tlCBfNE036gGJcv7Ijki7lS8YHxzb8OkZLJ5hAkckMnyJp4cxZbV6WKGFqqObXWFTIwJTXa6oAW3eEbpdYWcHApaL-Ing&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=SQL+Parameters+in+as&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=89e96c95c947f3f0).